# SQL merge duplicate non-key columns, overwriting NULL values

Tags: sql, join, merge

I'm trying to merge columns with the following format:

Table A:

```
Key Value
1   Null
2   "a"
3   "b"
```

Table B:

```
 Key  Value
 1    "c"
 2    NULL
 3    "b"
```

Output should be:

```
 Key Value
 1   "c"
 2   "a"
 3   "b"
```

If you just do a join on Key you get a duplicate Value column for both tables, but I want to merge the two value columns. In all cases they will have either (a) the same value or (b) one will be NULL and the other will have the value.

Comment: What's the expected result if you A and B for the same key, both has NULL, or a value (same or different)? Or if a key exists in just one of the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.key,coalesce(a.value,b.value)
from table_a  a
join table_b b on a.key=b.key
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this, given your 2 conditions is `UNION`:

```
SELECT key, value FROM TableA WHERE value IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT key, value FROM TableB WHERE value IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Is there any way to get this working with other columns present in one but not both tables?

Comment: @TannerPhillips the UNION operator is applicable only on datasets with the same number of columns (with the same data types in some databases).